# Import Less-Files from Classpath (Bootstrap Webjars)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, gradle, less

I want to generate my CSS-Files from Less-Files via LessCss-Gradle-Plugin (https://github.com/obecker/gradle-lesscss-plugin).

In my build.gradle I added the webjar-dependencies for bootstrap and so on..

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':pet-clinic-data')
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.2.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.3.2.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.3.2.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:0.45'
implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:2.2.4'
implementation 'org.webjars:jquery-ui:1.11.4'
implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.6'
runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:2.3.2.RELEASE'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.3.2.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-tx', version: '5.2.8.RELEASE'
}
```

And my lesscss-Task:

```
lesscss {
source = fileTree('src/main/less') {
    include '**/*.less'

}
dest = "$buildDir/resources/main/static/resources/css"

dependencies {
    compile 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.6'
    compileClasspath 'org.webjars:bootstrap:3.3.6'
}
}
```

I have some less-Files that require Elements from classes in the bootstrap-webjar (for example: label-success). I have the webjar in my external dependencies, but how can I use the @Import-Statement to link to that?
I tried something like:

```
@import "classpath: resources/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "classpath:META- 
 INF/resources/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/less/bootstrap.less"
```